# Limit 1 to 12 Swift textfield

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, mobile, logic

How can I limit the input in the textfield of 1 to 12 in this code?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        let texto = textfieldNumero.text ?? ""
        
        guard let rango = Range(range, in: texto) else {return true}
        
        let textoActualizado = texto.replacingCharacters(in: rango, with: string)
        
        let numero = 0
        let numeros = 13
      
        
        
        while textoActualizado > numero.description || textoActualizado <= numeros.description {
            return textoActualizado.count <= 2
        }
         
         
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an example of what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: Do you want to limit the input between 1 and 12 **characters** -- so `12345` is valid, but `1234567890123456789` is not? Or, do you wan to limit the input to **values** between 1 and 12 -- so `1`, `5`, `11`, `12` are all valid, but `0`, `16`, `27`, etc are not?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""

    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }

    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

    return updatedText.count < 13 && updatedText.count > 0
}
```